# VS2012 JavaScript debugger does not get my changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm debugging a JavaScript function in a web application using Visual Studio 2012. After I edit the file, when the application is run, it doesn't use my modified version. Instead it uses the old, outdated version.

If I set a breakpoint in the beginning of the function, for instance, the breakpoint is removed as soon as the script (let's say, `myScript.js`) is loaded; if I insist settting it again, a new window is opened (`myScript.js [dynamic]`) with the outdated code and the breakpoint is set.

Why my changes keep being ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> ought to be enough to force your browser fetch everything afresh from the server... the browser does cache some of these things.